# The html2pdf package with higher value than 1 in the scale property, makes the pagebreak a bit off

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I'm using the html2pdf [html2pdf](https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/) package to create pdf file from some html elements. The problem is, that the scale property with the default value (1), makes the pdf quality pretty bad, so I need at least to set it to 2, that makes a good quality. However, if the scale property is more than 1, the pagebreak property doesn't cut the element where it should, and the new page is overlapping the previous page, like that:
[image]
You can barely see it, but it will be worse with next pagebreak. This here is curently at sixth pagebreak, at the first one, you can't see it, but as I said, more you have of these breakpages, it more overlaps the previous page.
Is there any solution for that kind of problem?